# Best way to check connectivity using AFNetworking 2 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I want to check if user device is connected to internet or not before make a request to server. For this i'm doing this in `AppDelegate` class

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self connectivity];
}
    -(void)connectivity
    {
        [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){

        }];

        // Set the reachabilityManager to actively wait for these events
        [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
    }
```

and when i make any request i do

```
AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].networkReachabilityStatus;
BOOL con = (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN);
//BOOL con =[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;//give same result as networkReachabilityStatus
```

But first time when i make request it gives me `NO` and after some time it gives correct value. Please suggest the best way to monitor connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can check property *networkReachabilityStatus*:

```
AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].networkReachabilityStatus;
BOOL rechable = (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN);
```

If you want to try do smth while the *status* is *AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown*, you can use:

```
BOOL rechable = (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown);
```

P.S.

Checking of the reachability is asynchronous operation, see [SCNetworkReachabilityRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/), therefore you can't get networkReachabilityStatus in the *applicationDidFinishLaunching* method.

Comment: If i call my `connectivity` method from `applicationDidBecomeActive` as in question and then if i check `networkReachabilityStatus` as your suggestion i get same result as  `[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;` and if don't call `connectivity` method then i always get `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown`.

Comment: Before check _networkReachabilityStatus_ you should call -(void)startMonitoring and wait while it invoke your callback. Before it's called your callback status is  AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown. If you call  _networkReachabilityStatus_ from _ applicationDidBecomeActive_ you always will get  Unknown. I repeat: "Checking of the reachability is asynchronous operation"